# Function that doens`t let use buttons in app without a bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm developing a Bluetooth app that controls a little robot, it has a button on top that says "connect" and connects with the robot and bellow are buttons that control the robot, I want to add a function that doesn't let the buttons be clicked without a connection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the buttons to be disabled by default. Then, when a connection has been established, set the buttons to be enabled. Remember to disable them again once a disconnection occurs.

Comment: In terms of code , how can that be done ? Im new to programming